# I screwed my Computer by disabling my account using WMIC

Tags: user-accounts, wmi

I used the command--- path WIN32_USERACCOUNT where(name="user01") set disabled="true"

My account is disabled and Im running in safe mode just so i can get my question answered... how do I enable my account? Im really desperate so please respond ASAP

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why did you run that command?

Answer (score 2):

```
net user AccountName /active:yes
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are on XP, goto Control panel, administrative tools, computer management, under local users and groups goto the user tab, right click your username and uncheck Account is disabled box.